# Why do I get this error?

Tags: php, pagination, kohana, kohana-3

I study Kohana 3.2 and pagination. But I get error `ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Request::$uri`.

Where is the problem?

Pagination class (module)

```
switch ($this->config['current_page']['source'])
        {
            case 'query_string':
                return URL::site(Request::current()->uri).URL::query(array($this->config['current_page']['key'] => $page));

            case 'route':
                return URL::site(Request::current()->uri(array($this->config['current_page']['key'] => $page))).URL::query();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Request::current()->uri()` instead of `Request::current()->uri`.